# Why does this JavaScript object not have an href property?

Tags: jquery

I have been working on this assignment all night and it is done except one part.

```
window.location.href = searchresults.find('.active').attr('href');
```

The redirect works fine but it isn't pulling the href data. It is retrieved as undefined. I know I'm going to feel silly after realizing the mistake.

```
<div id="searchresults" class="round" style="display: block;">
<ul>
<li class="active">
<a href="#">
<img src="ajax.jpg">
<span>words</span>
</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Not enough information, I' afraid...

Comment: Show us your complete code -> http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: `console.log(searchresults)`? and `console.log(searchresults.find('.active'))` to debug it :)

Comment: Or use the script debugger in the developer tools for your browser

Comment: Can you show us the HTML that is being checked for the `href`?

Comment: just trying to pull href data from searchresults ul li .active. I see lots of examples online but they are all for $(this) and I can't seem to adapt it.

Comment: My crystal ball tells me you actually should use `.filter('.active')` instead of `.find('.active')`.

Comment: Well, the `<li class="active">` element does in fact not have a href attribute. The `<a>` element inside it does, perhaps that's what you wanted to select?

Comment: Juhana, you were right. I needed to walk it down one more to the <a>. put it in the answer block so I can give you a kiss

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your code you need to find `.active a`

so:

```
$('#searchresults').find('.active a').attr('href');
```